# Login form: @RequestMapping cannot handle the POST request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new to Spring.

I'm trying to validate a form using annotations that I put in `UserForm` Class.

Somehow post method does not run at all.

I can see the POST request in the browser but the controller POST method won't run.

Here is my `LoginController` Class:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Map<String, Object> model) {
        UserForm loginUser = new UserForm();
        model.put("userForm", loginUser);

        return "Login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doLogin(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("userForm") UserForm userForm,
            BindingResult result, 
            Map<String, Object> model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "Login";
        }

        return "Home";
    }
}
```

Any help pointers appreciated .

**Edit:**
Here is my form:

```
<form:form action="/bookmarks/login" method="POST" commandName="userForm">
    <label for="idInput">Username:</label>
    <form:input type="text" path="username" placeholder="Username" />
    <div><form:errors path="username" cssClass="error"/></div>
    <br>
    <label for="idInput">Passwors:</label>
    <form:input type="password" path="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <div><form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/></div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" value="login">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

This is my `security.xml` with added `login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"`. This actually solved my problem, but I can not fully explain why:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    ...
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/" 
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
            <!-- authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true" /> --> <!-- /login.html?error=true -->
        <!-- default-target-url="/homepage.html" -->
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url 
            pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/studentRegister" access="permitAll"/> -->
        <security:intercept-url 
            pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
        <security:logout 
            logout-success-url="/login?logout=true"
            invalidate-session="true"
            delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
        <security:session-management
            invalid-session-url="/login"></security:session-management>
    </security:http>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="bg.jwd.bookmarks.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />
    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider
            user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
</beans>
```

Comment: What's the response code from your POST request ? Can you show us the html form you are using and the ```UserForm``` object ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I posted the code for the login form and the security settings above. `UserForm` is completely standard. Тhere was not a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I found solution for my problem. I just added `login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"` to form-login tag in my security.xml. Now the POST request is acceptable.

Edit:

Hello,
I have another problem with this code.
Now I go through `POST` request and already have validation but when I try to log in with the correct username & password Spring redirects me back to the login form. (`Spring 4.0.3.RELEASE`).

Comment: Hello, Kindly check your default login succes url inside your Security config file. Change it to where you want to go after log in.